# A proper tool for removing a PEX pipe from a fitting barb

Tags: pex

When a pinch crimp has to be removed and re-done, what is the proper tool to remove the PEX pipe from a barb after removing the clamp and cutting of the pipe?

I thought of using the PEX pipe cutter's blade but am afraid it would mar the ribs on the barb and cause a leak when it's subsequently re-used.

In my particular case I am using a 3/4 elbow like this with a PEX pipe which is white on the o/s and black on the i/s if it matters.

[image]

So if I had to undo and re-do this kind of connection, I would open one of the pinch rings and cut off the pipe, but don't know how to remove what's left under the former crimp:

[image]

Comment: This may sound obvious, but in some cases you can just pull it off with your hand strength. At least in some cases that has worked for me. I have read (not sure if I've tried...) that you may be able to re-use the pipe end that way. Say for instance if you were just replacing a damaged fitting (e.g., burst from freezing).

Comment: A heat gun for 20-30 seconds worked for me with this connection (1/2" Pexa). Pulled off like butter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a utility knife to score the pipe. Or a pair of wire cutter pliers. Leave a little extra pipe on the end so you can grab it with the pliers and peel the pipe off.

Comment: Is there a concern that cutting PEX too deep would mar the fitting and cause a leak?

Comment: If your t is a brass t, then I wouldn't imagine you would really make a cut in it that would affect performance of the port. I'd actually be surprised if you made a cut into the brass to begin with.

Comment: A poly (plastic) fitting is more likely to be scratched. But I think with care that could be avoided or minimized.

Answer (score 3):

If you've ever actually removed pex from fittings with a utility knife, you'll find it is very easy to score the brass. It's impossible to tell if it will leak or not (now or in a year).

Do not score the brass ever, ask any plumber, you may be lucky a few times and then the one time you are not, you will have a leak behind the wall.

I put a cup of water in the microwave for a couple minutes, then dunk the fitting in it for a minute. Pliers pull it off like butter. I've also heard of people using blowtorch or heat gun. You don't need much heat!

I've also heard that you can use a crimp ring removal tool: faster removing the ring, use same tool on the pex in 3-4 places as this will stretch the pex without touching the brass ribs; then remove with pliers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this Home Depot cutter:

[image: ![enter image description here]

([Husky 7 in. Diagonal Pliers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-7-in-Diagonal-Pliers-48056/203287739))

gripping the crimp between the 2 blades turning the cutter and it pops open, then cut the pipe with a utility knife.

Comment: Is there a concern that cutting PEX too deep would mar the fitting and cause a leak?

Comment: I never had any issue, but use common sense and cut only pipe but a little scar on the fitting is no problem.

Comment: I would be surprised if you cut deep enough to make a scar that would not hold pressure. Use a new sharp blade and you don't need to cut hard. I have also rocked a straight edge blade instead of a pulling score.

Answer (score 1):

Cut your crimp off as described. Using a heat gun, start waving it at your connection while pulling the two apart. You just don't want to get things to hot as the fumes probably are not healthy. I held the fitting in a vise with the intent of re-using the fitting...it comes off pretty easy after it warms up. It would probably work out in the field where it may not be as easy but the fitting comes off pretty easily once it gets the right temp.
Good Luck TC

Comment: PS                                                                                                                             
 You can wiggle the piece of pipe as you go to help loosen things up if you have enough to grab onto, otherwise if its too short. I used a large pair of electrician type pliers to grab onto and "pinch" the pipe as it softens and just rip it off when it gets soft enough to do so.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you edit your comment into your post? That's where the full answer should be. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.